# applicationwillfinishaunching handler not working applescript xcode

Tags: xcode, applescript, interface-builder, handler, applescript-objc

My `on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)` handler isn't working. It works with my "xib" IB, but it doesn't work with my ".storyboard" IB. Where in the IB should I look? I have searched quite a bit looking for anything that says "applicationWillFinnishLaunching" but no luck. The handler only works if my main storyboard is an ".xib" file but when I make it a ".storyboard" it doesn't work.

Comment: This is the same question still open on your other thread. And it's completely hard to understand what you want. It seems (seeing this and your other questions)  you don't even know the basics of working with XCODE and I'd recommend you to do some more training and basic tutorials

Comment: @Pat_Morita I have been using xcode for 4 months now, and I am very familiar with how to use it. When I can't figure something out, I ask stack overflow. I question I was asking you earlier is: Where is the handler applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification) linked to the interface builder, because the problem isn't with my code, its with the storyboard. What really confuses me though, is that the handler is called when I use a ".xib" IB instead of a ".storyboard" IB (I just thought that might be helpful for figuring out the problem). This is the best way to explain my problem.

Comment: This is exactly what i mean. applicationWillFinishLaunching_ is a handler called through the applications delegate. The applications delegate is linked in IB. And not the handler itself. And this is some very basic stuff in XCode. And the IB is the interface builder. The nice drag and drop tool you build your storyboard with. Also some very basic stuff. Please check the connections on a NEW created XCode project (as told exactly like that in another same question of you) like in the following answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new project and check the connection you see in the image below.
Then try to find if the same connection is broken in your project and recreate it.

[image: AppDelegate connect]

Comment: I am using a storyboard file not an xib file for my interface. How can I get this same link on a story board? Image below: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzaQ6L3vezqkV3lNMk5GNFp0ZkU

Comment: Don't use applescript with storyboards. Some reasons: There's almost no support out there!! Search for "Xcode Storyboard Applescript" and you will find.... almost nothing. Less supported = Flat learning curve. Storyboards are based on ViewControllers and each scene is handled on its own.  Impossible to map with ApplescriptObjC's limited possibilities e.g. you cannot subclass anything. Rebuild it with a xib. That's a lot faster to develop with applescript.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I will rebuild it on an XIB. I dont really know the terminology for this, but how do you add actions and popover windows? Example: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzaQ6L3vezqkYzVjVmU1dUtrRHM

Comment: And.. a side note: if there's an answer to your question you should accept it by clicking the accept icon. Or if there's a comment that helps you please up vote it.